# two machines direct link + connection through switch

Tags: routing, gateway

This is crosspost from [Super Users](https://superuser.com/questions/1343230/two-machines-direct-link-connection-through-switch), since it might attract more people here.

I have been trying for the last couple of days to get a setup like the one below working.

I have 
a server Ubuntu 16.04 with two network cards, 1 1Gbit, 1 10Gbit
a windows machine windows 10 with two network cards, 1 1Gbit, 1 10Gbit

I can ping from the windows machine to the servers 192.168.1.200 address, but not to the 192.168.0.200. The windows machine can also access the internet just fine.

from the server I can ping the windows machine, i.e. 192.168.1.49.
I can also ping some of the hosts in the 192.168.0.0/24 net, but not the default gateway. The server also have no connection to the internet.

So my question is, how do I get this to work, it seems fairly simple - I want the two machines to communicate all 192.168.1.0/24 traffic directly via the fast 10Gbs link and everything else should go via the default gateway.

I have tried all kinds of routing setup on the server, I have tried to follow the guide here: https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Two_Default_Gateways_on_One_System - but my setup is slightly different, since I dont have a default gateway in the 192.168.1.0/24 net.

The 10Gb networks is a new addition, before adding those, everyhing was peachy - I added the 10gb netcards to get a fast connection to the server so I could mount iscsi on a fast low latency connection.

I hope you bright people have good ideas.

Thanks
Bjørn

```
                                  Internet
                                     |
                                     |
                                     |
                                     |
                                     |
                                     |
                                     |
                            --------------------
                            |                  |
                ------------| Router/Switch    |-----------
                |           |  192.168.0.1     |          |
                |           --------------------          |
                |                                         |
                |                                         |
                |                                         |
                |                                         |
                |                                         |
                |                                         |
                |                                         |
      Network Card 1 (ens192)                     Network Card 1 (eth0)
                |                                         |
       192.168.0.200 (s)                           192.168.0.29 (d)
      --------------------                      ---------------------
      |                  |                      |                   |
      |     Server 1     |                      |  Windows client   |
      |                  |                      |                   |
      --------------------                      ---------------------
         192.168.1.200 (s)                         192.168.1.49 (s)
      |                                         |
      Network Card 2 (ens161)                     Network Card 2 (eth1)
                |                                         |
                |                                         |
                |               Direct 10GbE              |
                -------------------------------------------
```

## /etc/network/interfaces

```
    # The loopback network interface
    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback

    auto ens192
    iface ens192 inet static
    address 192.168.0.200
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.0.1
    dns-nameservers 192.168.0.201
    dns-domain smith.local
    dns-domain cloud.local


    auto ens161
    iface ens161 inet static
        address 192.168.1.200
        netmask 255.255.255.0

        # fast interface route
        post-up ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev ens161 src 192.168.1.200 table rt2
        post-up ip route add default 192.168.1.49 dev ens161 table rt2

        post-up ip rule add from 192.168.1.200/32 table rt2
        post-up ip rule add to 192.168.1.200/32 table rt2
```

## route -n

```
    Kernel IP routing table
    Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
    0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ens192
    192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ens192
    192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ens161
```

## ip rule show

```
    0:      from all lookup local
    32764:  from all to 192.168.1.200 lookup rt2
    32765:  from 192.168.1.200 lookup rt2
    32766:  from all lookup main
    32767:  from all lookup default
```

## ip route list table rt2

```
192.168.1.0/24 dev ens161  scope link  src 192.168.1.200
```

## ip route list table main

```
    default via 192.168.0.1 dev ens192 onlink
    192.168.0.0/24 dev ens192  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.200
    192.168.1.0/24 dev ens161  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.200
```

## windows route print

```
    ===========================================================================
    Interface List
     14...00 02 c9 4d 4d fc ......Mellanox ConnectX-2 Ethernet Adapter #2
     19...30 9c 23 81 a4 53 ......Intel(R) I211 Gigabit Network Connection
      3...00 19 0e 0b 54 55 ......Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
      1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
    ===========================================================================

    IPv4 Route Table
    ===========================================================================
    Active Routes:
    Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
              0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.0.1     192.168.0.29     25
            127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
            127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
      127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
          192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.0.29    281
         192.168.0.29  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.0.29    281
        192.168.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.0.29    281
          192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.1.49    271
         192.168.1.49  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.49    271
        192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.49    271
            224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
            224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.0.29    281
            224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.1.49    271
      255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
      255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.0.29    281
      255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.49    271
    ===========================================================================
    Persistent Routes:
      None

    IPv6 Route Table
    ===========================================================================
    Active Routes:
     If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
      1    331 ::1/128                  On-link
      1    331 ff00::/8                 On-link
    ===========================================================================
    Persistent Routes:
      None
```

Comment: Can you post also the routing table from your windows machine (route print)? As you have described, it seems the windows machine has the routing working but not on ubuntu.

Comment: @BernardWei done, route from windows added

Comment: I am not sure if it makes any difference. The ubuntu server is a virtual machine on another physical machine (esxi) - both network cards are connected to the same virtual switch on esxi (since I could not figure out how to configure a network card to use a different virtual switch)

Comment: Can't see anything obvious in the network setup and routing table. It is strange that you can't ping the gateway from the server. Does the network cards on Ubuntu initialized and running fine? Check ifconfig output.

Comment: It works :-) Turns out I am just a butthole :-) I managed to make another virtual switch in esxi, put the 10gb card over there and move the virtual netcard to that switch and when I started the server again, everything just worked. Let this be a lesson for all, different physical networks must be on different virtual switches in esxi

Comment: Cool. May be you can post an answer to your question describing this and close this question. Cheers.

Comment: cant close it, I dont have enough reputation.

Comment: Don't worry about closing it; at least mark your answer as the chosen one.

Answer (score 1):

0
down vote
accept
I digged more into why I could not create another virtual switch and found out that you are supposed to be able to, so I managed to make another virtual switch in esxi, put the 10gb card over there and move the virtual netcard to that switch and when I started the server again, everything just worked.

Let this be a lesson for all, different physical networks must be on different virtual switches in esxi.

So in reality there was no problem at all, this was in reality a esxi problem and not a linux problem. Linux was sending the packages correctly, but esxi was dropping them apparently.